# Exporting Image using Export.image.toDrive saves multiple images

Tags: google-earth-engine, export

I am trying to export an image to Google Drive but after the Task is done running I can see multiple images exported to the drive. Shouldn't it export just one image?

The code I'm using is

```
var pak_boundaries = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level0")
              .filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Pakistan'));
              
var landcover_esa =ee.ImageCollection("ESA/WorldCover/v100").first()

var viz_esa = {
 bands: ['Map'],
};

var pak_geometries = pak_boundaries.geometry()
var pak_landcover = landcover_esa.clip(pak_geometries);  

Export.image.toDrive({
 image:pak_landcover,
 description:'pak_landcover_esa_10s',
 scale: 10,
 maxPixels: 23741603435,
 region:pak_geometries
});
```

This is what my Drive looks like:

[image: Screenshot of my Google Drive]

Ideally I want to see just one GeoTIFF image.

Answer (score 2):

There's a 4GB limit built into the GeoTIFF standard.  So large outputs have to be split into pieces smaller than that.

Comment: But the combined size of all these files is less than 500Mb

Comment: That's including compression and/or masked pixels.  The sizing is done based on the raw number of pixels and shoots for a file size of 1G each.

Comment: Hey, I've downloaded the files and can see that they have numbers appended to them after the description I picked. For example, I have files named pak_landcover_esa_10s-0000000000-0000000000, pak_landcover_esa_10s-0000000000-0000065536, pak_landcover_esa_10s-0000000000-0000131072 and so on. Would you happen to know what these numbers mean?

Comment: Those are pixels coordinates of the upper left corner of the tile.